# What description do we want for the "ai-community" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

This has been proposed:

> For questions about current affairs about various types of contributions/theories proposed by different groups/communities identifying themselves as AI researchers/practitioners/enthusiasts.

This is not a subject I've given much thought to, but it's important in that it defines what we mean by "AI community" in context so **please post any thoughts, suggestions, revisions or alternate proposals.**

Comment: Self-learning is a tag that caught my eye...It has questions on self-learning ai and also beginners asking for learning resources...What should be done about that?

Comment: @DuttaA great point about "self-learning".  I just killed that tag (per the confusion) and replaced with "unassisted-learning", except for the handful of questions that were actually "getting-started".